# Why the color is falling off from a Bristol cardboard laser printed?

Tags: print-production

I think the picture is very explicit of what is the problem I'm facing when the printed cardboard is folded. Whay is that happens?

The cardboard is a Bristol 180 printed in a OKI podwer tonner printer.

What solution can I have for prevent that? What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user287001 that tricks can be useful in a hurry moment, but this product needs to be perfect because is an hotel welcome folder. Need a solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toner, unlike ink, is *not* absorbed by the substrate. Toner merely sits *on top* of the substrate and is heated to bind to the *surface*. If you fold or bend the substrate, you stretch it, and toner will not stretch to match any change.

What you're doing "wrong" is expecting toner to act like ink.

Comment: But why in a Xerox tonner printer is not happend the same? In other deppartment we have one, and recently to calendars was printed and when the print is bend, the color stick to the cardboard and do not fall off making that "white line" in the bend.

Comment: Also say that the problem is not only in the bending zone, also when you scrape the print with your nails, the color fall off to ... Even fall off with a little fingers contact. I think could be a technical problem with the heater? Or with the tonner itself?

Comment: If toner is coming off simply with a touch, then yes, there's a technical issue with the printer. Or the stock you are printing on is not designed to hold toner.

Comment: not with a simple touch, but with a some short use in the hands yes. I think that isn't normal at all. And isn't normal too that happens the same when I scrape the surface, right?